# How to repair cupboard hing that tore off particle board

Tags: repair, screws, cabinets, particle-board, hole-repair

The top hinges of the cupboard have been torn out of the particle board taking a big chunk with it and leaving quite a deep crater with just a couple of dents for where the holes used to be as illustrated below.

The picture doesn't really show the depth of the ripped hole, but it's fairly deep and those screw holes are really just dents now.

Is there a fairly quick and easy way to fix this?

[image]

Comment: @mmathis I'm not sure if those answers would be good for my predicament since that question doesn't seem to involve screws.

Comment: I think the same answers mostly apply - move the hinge down or rotate the door 180 so that the handle edge becomes the hinge edge.

Comment: Another fix could be to use a strong adhesive like gorilla glue or construction adhesive. Glue the broken piece back on and clamp it tight. Re-drill your holes and re-attach the hinge. Alternatively, you could use a metal strap and place it over the broken opening, over lapping the hole by an inch on each side, attach that with a few screws. Use a short bolt and nut to attach the hinge to the strap. Do this before attaching the strap to the broken area.